# How do you rerun two python scripts like in a loop

Tags: python

For example, I want to run this code in a python file titled "file1"

```
print("HI")
import file2
```

which would then call "file2"

```
print("Hello")
import file1
```

How would I continue this loop without ending??

Comment: That's not how modules or `import` is intended to be used. Circular imports (file1 imports file2 which imports file1 again) cause ImportErrors. If you want a piece of code that can be repeated, make a function. Import only in one direction, like a tree.

Comment: This doesn't work, for a good reason. This will just be an infinite loop of the files calling each other. What ***exactly*** are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm really trying to make a 2 python scripts with tkinter which could alternately open from one another

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

file.py

```py
import file2

while True:
    print('Hi')
    file2.hello()
```

file2.py

```py
def hello():
    print('Hello')
```